# Finite difference solution of steady-state diffusion equation with variable material properties

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, finite-differences

I'm trying to use a finite difference method to solve the steady-state neutron diffusion equation in a nuclear reactor:

$$ D(x) \nabla^2 \phi(x) + \left( \frac{\nu(x)}{k} \Sigma_f(x) - \Sigma_a(x) \right) \phi(x) = 0 $$

When the material properies $D$, $\nu$, $\Sigma_f$ and $\Sigma_a$ are uniform through the reactor, this reduces to

$$ \nabla^2 \phi(x) + B^2 \phi(x) = 0 $$

where $B^2 = \frac{\frac{\nu}{k} \Sigma_f - \Sigma_a}{D}$. I can create the matrix equation

$$ A \mathbf{u} = \lambda \mathbf{u} $$

and the solution I'm looking for is the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest magnitude eigenvalue $\lambda$. That eigenvalue is the $-B^2$ required for the solution to be valid, and using $k=1$ (as is true for steady-state conditions), the required material properties of the reactor can be determined.

However, I don't know what matrix equation to construct when the material properties vary. In practice I want to have a number of regions each with different properties. When solving analytically for a one-dimensional reactor with two regions, the conditions at the interface are $\phi_1(x_{int}) = \phi_2(x_{int})$ and $D_1 \frac{d\phi_1}{dx}(x_{int}) = D_2 \frac{d\phi_2}{dx}(x_{int})$. Ideally, the properties of all but one of the regions would be defined, with the properties of the remaining region being determined by the conditions required to make $k$ equal to 1, as in the uniform properties case.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Your parameters are constant inside each region? Or can vary in each region?

Comment: Also what are your boundary conditions? And in the single-region case, why do you only consider the largest $\lambda$?

Comment: For the model I want to create, the properties are constant within each region, but I generalised the problem a little since I figure that's the same as having step changes in the property functions over the whole reactor. I've realised I should probably reword that second bit to replace highest with smallest magnitude - I choose the eigenvalue closest to zero, and they all happen to be negative. That corresponds to the fundamental mode, which is the only physically valid solution because it's the only one where $\phi$ is positive through the whole domain.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you required $\phi > 0$. What are the boundary conditions at the border of the reactor? $\nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n} = 0$?

Comment: For a full reactor the boundary conditions are $\phi = 0$, but since I only want to look at symmetrical reactors, I can model just part of the of it with $\phi = 0$ on the reactor exterior and $\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$ on the plane/line/point of symmetry (for 3/2/1 dimensions).

Comment: Bah, I mean $\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0$ of course.

Comment: So you will need more conditions to restrict the possible solutions: you can solve the Poisson equation $\Delta \phi = -g(x)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions for any positive $g$; $\phi$ can have no local minima and so is positive inside the reactor. Then set $B^2(x) = g(x)/\phi(x)$.